# PDO update query set JSON string

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

can i update table and set JSON string with PDO? Because PDO is removing "\" character and diacritics is not working please help.

```
->query("UPDATE products SET name = '".$new_name."' WHERE shop = '1' AND id = 'a9t8'");
```

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2864740). It will Fix/Avoid the Problem (and it might reveal an additional problem with encoding), which is why I've marked it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `PDO` yet still open to `SQL` injection.

You should `prepare` your query, that's the whole point of `PDO`

```
$sql = "UPDATE products SET name = :new_name WHERE shop = :shop AND id = :id";
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(":new_name", $new_name);
$statement->bindValue(":shop", '1');
$statement->bindValue(":id", 'a9t8');
$statement->execute();
```